# How to have one cell value dependent on multiple cells (>2)

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, decision-tree

I have a fixed value, at the end of a row within a table, let us say 9,000. 
I want this value of 9,000 to be dependent on entering yes or no in the three cells (in the same row as the 9,000 value) that precede the value of 9,000.

For example:

```
if YES to question 1, then multiply 9,000 by .05, call this new value `x` 
if NO to question 1, then multiply 9,000 by 1. call this new value `x` 
if YES to question 2, then multiply x by .1, call this new value `x_2` 
if NO to question 2, then multiply x by 1, call this new value `x_2` 
if YES to question 3, then multiply x_2 by .075, call this new value `x_3` 
if NO to question 3, then multiply x_2 by 1, call this new value `x_3`
```

I tried using the following if statement:

Let us say cell D1=9,000

```
=IF(A1="YES",D1*.05,
     IF(A1="NO",D1,
         IF(A2="YES",D1*.1,
             IF(A2="NO",D1,
                 IF(A3="YES",D1*.075,
                     IF(A3="NO",D1,"")
                   )
               )
           )
       )
   )
```

My problem is once an answer of YES is entered, the value of 9,000 changes to a new value.

Once another YES is entered, the value of 9,000 is again changed.

However, I want the new value obtained from the first YES to be the value that gets affected by the second and/or third YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to simplify your problem

Here you can see that the result you will have will be something like `A*B*C*D`, with:
A= 9000
B= 0.05 (if Q1=`YES`), B= 1 (if Q1=`NO`)
C= 0.1 (if Q2=`YES`), C=1 (if Q2=`NO`)
D= 0.075 (if Q3=`YES`), D=1 (if Q3= `FALSE`)

So we can change your formula in something like:

```
=D1 * IF(A1="YES",0.05,1) * IF(A2="YES",0.1,1) * IF(A3="YES",0.075,1)
```

(supposing, according to the example you gave, that `D1` is the `9000`, `A1` is the Question1's answer, `A2` is the Question2's answer and `A3` is the Question3's answer)

If you want that something special occurs when an answer is neither `YES` nor `NO` (like if someone answer `TEST` in a question), you can enroll all with some checking condition like:

```
=IF(AND( OR(A1="YES",A1="NO"), OR(A2="YES",A2="NO"), OR(A3="YES",A3="NO") ), 
    D1 * IF(A1="YES",0.05,1) * IF(A2="YES",0.1,1) * IF(A3="YES",0.075,1), 
    "Please answer YES or NO to the questions")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was overthinking it.